# Nested " for loop" not working for opening and aggregating csv files

Tags: r, for-loop, file-listing

Can anyone tell me why these nested for loop are not working

```
nom_fichiers <- c("_Alias","_Autres_Codes","_Autres_Coord", "_Descriptif","_EntitesHydroBDLISA","_EntitesHydroBDRHFV1",
                 "_Evenements","_Fonctions","_MassesEau","_Proprietaires", "_Qual_Analyses","_Qual_Dossiers_Analyses",
                 "_Qual_Echantillons","_Qual_Operations","_Qual_Prelevements","_Qual_Sites_Mesures","_Stations_Hydro","_Usages")

liste_nom_fichiers<-as.list(as.character(nom_fichiers))

# First for loop    
for (i in seq.int(liste_nom_fichiers))
{

    liste_fichier<-list()

    filelist = list.files(path ="C:/Users/TB60063/Desktop/Export_ADES_POINTS_QUALITE",
                          pattern = paste0(liste_nom_fichiers[[i]], ".txt"), recursive = T)


    # Second for loop       
    for(i in seq.int(filelist)){

      # Opening files

      liste_fichier[[i]]<- read.csv(filelist[i], header = T,sep = "|", dec =".")           

    }

    nom_output <- assign(paste0("tbl", liste_nom_fichiers[[i]]), do.call("rbind", liste_fichier))

    # Enregistrement du fichier brut

    nom_fichier<-paste0("tbl", liste_nom_fichiers, "_", "brut") 
    chemin <- paste0("./data_brutes/", nom_fichier, ".csv")
    write.csv2(nom_output, chemin)


    return(nom_output)

}
```

If i run the second manually (iteration by iteration it works) but if I run the whole script it's not working.

I probably miss something.

Comment: Shouldn't nom_fisher<-paste0("tbl",liste_nom_fichiers,"_","brut") have an index for liste_nom_fichiers?

Comment: Thanks @Brett DeWoody. It was actually an oversight. But still my nested loops are not working.  Did you see something else wrong in my for loops structure ?